# How ActiveMQ is different from Kafka in terms of horizontal scaling?

Tags: apache-kafka

ActiveMQ Horizontal scaling is explained here:
http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html

Can anyone tell me the "difference" between ActiveMQ and Kafka in terms of "horizontal scaling" (in a simplified language)?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

A Kafka Broker has different features from ActiveMQ.

When you connect a Kafka Broker broker, you should send events or subscribe to a topic, you do not connect yo a single server, but to a broker. If you are subscribing to topic that are only stored in a node, you will be redirect to this node.

Each topic has it own **Replication Factor** and **Partition Number**. Each partition will be stored in a different node, if possible. Each partition will be replicated according with its replication factor, in a different node.